# Answer using sampling method

Tags: probability, statistics

An urn holds 60 red marbles and 40 white marbles. Two sets of 30 marbles each are drawn with replacement
from the urn, and their colors are noted. What is the probability that the two sets differ by 8 or more red
marbles?

Comment: Find or approximate $P(|R_1-R_2|\geq8)$ where $R_1,R_2$ represent the number of reds in the two drawn sets. Here $R_1,R_2$ are iid with binomial distribution having parameters $n=30$ and $p=0.6$.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?